# Как исправить исчезновение выпадающего меню при наведении?

Tags: css, jquery

Есть проблема с отображение выпадающего меню. При наведении на элемент **«Меню»**, открывается подменю, которое закрывается, когда курсор покидает элемент **«Меню»**.

Как это исправить?

Прикладываю пример - https://jsfiddle.net/nqzf50wo/1/

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.nav {
  display: flex
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 30px
}

.nav-head {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 100px
}

.nav-submenu {
  background: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none
}

.nav-head:hover ~ .nav-submenu {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 1</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 2</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
    <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 3</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: используйте js для этого

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение - при наведении на родительский элемент показываем дочерний:

`.nav-item:hover .nav-submenu {}`

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.nav {
  display: flex
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 30px
}

.nav-head {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 100px
}

.nav-submenu {
  background: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-submenu {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 1</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 2</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 3</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Можно добавить легкую анимацию. Пример:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.nav {
  display: flex
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 30px
}

.nav-head {
  background: #333;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 100px
}

.nav-submenu {
  background: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-item:hover .nav-submenu {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 1</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 2</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-head">Меню 3</div>
    <ul class="nav-submenu">
      <li>Подменю 1</li>
      <li>Подменю 2</li>
      <li>Подменю 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```